# Joblib reuse parallel workers in nested function calls

Tags: python, joblib

I am trying to reuse workers while executing nested function calls. Here is the scenario...

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

def func1():
    with Parallel(n_jobs = -1) as parallel:
        var1 = parallel(delayed(func2)(i) for i in range(5))
        print(var1)

def func2(i):
    var2 = parallel(delayed(func3)(x, i) for x in range(5))
    return var2

def func3(x, i):
    return x+i

if __name__ == '__main__':
    func1()
```

I get an error in `func2()` that the `parallel` is not defined. How do I use context manager API for such nested loops?

Comment: Can you not pass the `parallel` context into func2?

Comment: @OneRaynyDay Can you give an example? Do you mean...
`var1 = parallel(delayed(func2)(i, parallel) for i in range(5))`
Then I get `NotImplementedError: pool objects cannot be passed between processes or pickled`

Comment: @OneRaynyDay you cant pass it, because it cannot be pickled. the delayed will execute func2 in another process and therefore it must pickle all the arguments and then read them back.